# Conservation of energy in ultraviolet catastrophe

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, statistical-mechanics

My question is just about the consistency of electromagnetism and statistical mechanics. If in those theories energy is conserved, how can it be that we derive the Rayleigh-Jeans equation, where energy appears not to be conserved. What's wrong? I know that in the real world we have to take into account quantum mechanics, but I'm not asking that. What I'm asking is how can it be that we derive something inconsistent with the conservation of energy from two theories in which energy is in fact conserved.

Comment: Isn't that taking into account conservation of energy alone isn't enough? If premises are wrong why the results should be correct or consistent with the premises themselves?